# I cannot see Ethereum accounts in Browser

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

There are 10 Ethereum accounts in Ganache. I work on a Truffle project. Whenever i run the following codes in Nodejs:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3("ws://localhost:8545");
var acc= Promise.resolve(web3.eth.getAccounts());
acc.then(function(ins){console.log(ins[0]);});
```

Address of the first account will be shown:

[image]

But i want to see that address in my browser. What is the appropriate code?

Comment: There is an appropriate solution code [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79840/access-to-smart-contracts-value-in-browser/82405#82405).

Comment: There is an appropriate solution code [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79840/access-to-smart-contracts-value-in-browser/82405#82405)

Comment: You should make a Jade file in first. After that, you determine a field in the Jade file so that it accepts the given value. After that, you can see the value in browser based on code you embedded in Jade. Take a look at:
[https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/jade-template-engine](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/jade-template-engine)

Answer (score 1):

In your working example, you are handling the result of `getAccounts` in an asynchronous manner:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
```

In your non-working example, you are wrongfully assuming that it runs synchronously to completion:

```
var acc=web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

---

Function `web3.eth.getAccounts` returns a `Promise` object which, when resolved, contains all the accounts which are unlocked on the node that your `web3` object is connected to.

Resolve this promise, and you should be good.

Comment: I am a beginner in programming and my knowledge about promise and JavaScript is low. Please clear more about resolve the promise.

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: How hard is it, even for a beginner, to take a working example (which you already have!!!) and use it instead of the non-working example???

Answer (score 1):

To see a contract's values in browser with `web3`, you should create some `.jade` file. For interacting with a smart contract from a browser, the workflow is this: There are 3 levels: 1) Blockchain level, 2) Nodejs level, and 3) UI/browser level. In "blockchain level" there is the given smart contract (that you have it). In "Nodejs level" there is the related JavaScript code that requires `web3` module and uses its methods. In "UI/browser level" there is your browser. The contract connects to Nodejs with `web3` and they send their data together. On the other hand ,Nodejs and browser send their data together, too. To see this sent data in the browser you should create some `.jade` file. Nodejs sends its data to that `.jade` file and you execute that file via your browser. In order to do this successfully, you need to know JavaScript programming in Nodejs.